# Play Integrity local verification

Tags: android, base64, playback, integrity

I am trying to integrate the play integrity check in my app to make sure that my app is not installed on a rooted Android device. I can successfully obtain the integrity token response as guided in the google [document](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#request). But I am trying to verify it in my locally and close the app if its installed on a rooted device. For that local verification, I am following the document [Decrypt and verify locally](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#decrypt-verify-locally). But I could not understand what is Base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey and Base64OfEncodedVerificationKey and from where I can obtain that.

Comment: Check the sample code in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77953152/9133569

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to go to Google Play Console -> Release -> Setup -> AppIntegrity -> Response encryption -> Change, choose "Manage and download my response encryption keys", generate key file (follow instructions in "Show instructions"), upload this file.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Any idea of where to find those keys for a debug app or not released on the store app ?

Comment: @Ben-J unfortunately no, but you can use internal testing in google play console