# Decrypt and verify locally Play Integrity API Token

Tags: java, android, jwe, google-play-integrity-api

I'm trying to implement Play Integrity API in my project. I already implement the logic in an Android app and send the token to my server. I want to decrypt and verify locally because the server don't and won't have internet connection. So I'm following the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#decrypt-verify-locally), but I'm struggling when getting the payload of the JWE. This is what I tried:

```
String playIntegrityToken = "eyJhbGciOiJBM...";
String base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey = "...";
byte[] decryptionBytes = Base64.decode(base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey);
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(decryptionBytes, 0, decryptionBytes.length, "AES");
JsonWebEncryption jwe = (JsonWebEncryption) JsonWebStructure.fromCompactSerialization(playIntegrityToken);
jwe.setKey(secretKey);
System.out.println(jwe.getPayload());
```

But I getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jose4j.lang.JoseException: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at org.jose4j.jwe.SimpleAeadCipher.decrypt(SimpleAeadCipher.java:114)
    at org.jose4j.jwe.SimpleAeadCipher.decrypt(SimpleAeadCipher.java:101)
    at org.jose4j.jwe.AesGcmContentEncryptionAlgorithm.decrypt(AesGcmContentEncryptionAlgorithm.java:79)
    at org.jose4j.jwe.JsonWebEncryption.decrypt(JsonWebEncryption.java:249)
    at org.jose4j.jwe.JsonWebEncryption.getPlaintextBytes(JsonWebEncryption.java:85)
    at org.jose4j.jwe.JsonWebEncryption.getPlaintextString(JsonWebEncryption.java:78)
    at org.jose4j.jwe.JsonWebEncryption.getPayload(JsonWebEncryption.java:93)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:620)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:853)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2168)
    at org.jose4j.jwe.SimpleAeadCipher.decrypt(SimpleAeadCipher.java:110)
    ... 7 more
```

The library I'm using is Jose4j in its 0.8.0 version.

I also tried changing the library that handle the JWE, for `Nimbus JOSE + JWT`, the library that decode the decryption key, the `SecretKeySpec`, the length, the algoritm , but nothing works, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you got any solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun googlePlayIntegrity(
    nonce: String
) = scope.launch {

    // cloudProjectNumber through Play Console.
    // get the nonce from your backend or generate it locally or just use a static one like "a0a008af421a4bb4e8344fb8a5103c7ea25226358cd65750f09f998b4bf13307" for testing

    val cloudProjectNumber = BuildConfig.GOOGLE_PLAY_CLOUD_PROJECT_NUMBER.toLong()

    val integrityManager = IntegrityManagerFactory.create(context)

    val integrityTokenRequest = IntegrityTokenRequest.builder()
        .setCloudProjectNumber(cloudProjectNumber)
        .setNonce(nonce)
        .build()

    integrityManager.requestIntegrityToken(integrityTokenRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Timber.d("integrity - Success")
            decryptIntegrityToken(it.token())
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Timber.d("integrity - Failure")
        }
}

private fun decryptIntegrityToken(integrityToken: String) {

    // base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey and base64OfEncodedVerificationKey are provided through Play Console.

    val base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey = ""
    val base64OfEncodedVerificationKey = ""

    val decryptionKeyBytes: ByteArray =
        Base64.decode(base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey, Base64.DEFAULT)

    // Deserialized encryption (symmetric) key.
    val decryptionKey: SecretKey = SecretKeySpec(
        /* key */ decryptionKeyBytes,
        /* offset */ 0,
        /* key length */ decryptionKeyBytes.size,
        /* algorithm */ "AES"
    )

    val encodedVerificationKey: ByteArray =
        Base64.decode(base64OfEncodedVerificationKey, Base64.DEFAULT)

    // Deserialized verification (public) key.
    val verificationKey: PublicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")
        .generatePublic(X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedVerificationKey))

    val jwe: JsonWebEncryption = JsonWebStructure.fromCompactSerialization(integrityToken) as JsonWebEncryption
    jwe.key = decryptionKey

    // This also decrypts the JWE token.
    val compactJws: String = jwe.payload

    val jws: JsonWebSignature =
        JsonWebStructure.fromCompactSerialization(compactJws) as JsonWebSignature
    jws.key = verificationKey

    // This also verifies the signature.
    val payload: String = jws.payload
    Timber.d("jws - $jws")
    Timber.d("payload - $payload")
}
```

Don't forget the correct imports:

```
import android.util.Base64
import org.jose4j.jwe.JsonWebEncryption
import org.jose4j.jws.JsonWebSignature
import org.jose4j.jwx.JsonWebStructure
import java.security.KeyFactory
import java.security.PublicKey
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec
import javax.crypto.SecretKey
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
```

And you'll need this JSON Web Token library in your build.gradle dependencies:

```
implementation("org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:0.9.4")
```

Comment: I've also tried the same but it resulted in the following exception :

```org.jose4j.lang.IntegrityException: A256KW key unwrap/decrypt failed.```

and

```checksum failed at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseWrapCipher.engineUnwrap(BaseWrapCipher.java:505)```

Am I missing anything ?