# What are Google Play Integrity constants AES_KEY_SIZE_BYTES, AES_KEY_TYPE and EC_KEY_TYPE

Tags: google-play-integrity-api

When decrypting and verifying the Google Play Integrity verdict as per official docs (https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict) the code snippet/samples shared uses these constants: `AES_KEY_SIZE_BYTES`, `AES_KEY_TYPE` and `EC_KEY_TYPE`

But the values of those are never mentioned. Can someone plase help, what are those values?

Comment: Check the sample code in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77953152/9133569

Comment: Yes M.Ed, that's the exact same code I wrote in the answer in JAVA. If you are looking for same code in Kotlin you can refer the code you mentioned. Thanks for pointing it out here, it might help others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After searching hours on the internet, I came across a youtube video ([Obtaining and Decoding the Integrity Verdict | Step 3 of Migrating to Play Integrity API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEygwc87Iak)) (obviously not from Google) which gave me the required answer. Here are the values for those constants:

AES_KEY_SIZE_BYTES: `decryptionKeyBytes.length`
AES_KEY_TYPE: `AES`
EC_KEY_TYPE: `EC`

So your final code should look something like this:

```
package com.example.sample
...
...
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.jose4j.jwe.JsonWebEncryption;
import org.jose4j.jws.JsonWebSignature;
import org.jose4j.jwx.JsonWebStructure;
import org.jose4j.lang.JoseException;
...
...


// base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey is provided through Play Console.
byte[] decryptionKeyBytes =
    Base64.decode(base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey, Base64.DEFAULT);

// Deserialized encryption (symmetric) key.
SecretKey decryptionKey =
    new SecretKeySpec(
        decryptionKeyBytes,
        /* offset= */ 0,
        decryptionKeyBytes.length,
        "AES");

// base64OfEncodedVerificationKey is provided through Play Console.
byte[] encodedVerificationKey =
    Base64.decode(base64OfEncodedVerificationKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
// Deserialized verification (public) key.
PublicKey verificationKey =
    KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")
        .generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedVerificationKey));
```

If you are using maven make sure you added these dependancies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-playintegrity</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev20220904-2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bitbucket.b_c</groupId>
    <artifactId>jose4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```