# Decrypt and verify locally Play Integrity API Token using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jwe, jose, google-play-integrity-api

Google gives an option to locally extract the play Integrity API Token. Even example with Java is provided [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#decrypt-verify-locally). But many servers are Node.js based. So, how can I decrypt the Play Integrity API token locally with Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Now Google API for Play Integrity is available. We don't need jose package. To work with google api:

`npm install @googleapis/playintegrity`

Then follow this code example:

```
const playintegrity = require("@googleapis/playintegrity");
...
...
...
const auth = new playintegrity.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFilename: __dirname + '/<key-file-name>.json',
  /* Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single, 
    space-delimited string.*/
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/playintegrity']
});
const authClient = await auth.getClient();

const client = await playintegrity.playintegrity({
  version: 'v1',
  auth: authClient
});

const createResponse = await client.v1
     .decodeIntegrityToken({ 
          integrity_token: req.body.integrity_token, 
          packageName: <package-name> 
     });

const payloadJson = createResponse.data.tokenPayloadExternal;

const nonce = Buffer.from(
          payloadJson.requestDetails.requestHash,
          "base64"
      ).toString(); /* the actual nonce message sent from app */
```

**22 September 2022:**

[This example](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#decrypt-verify-locally) shows how to extract **Json Web Signature (JWS)** from **Json Web Encryption (JWE)** token extracted from the **Play Integrity Token** using Google Play Console provided **Decryption key**,  which is verified with the Google Play Console provided **Verification key** to extract the actual **payload** JSON string.

But the problem is, it's written in **Java** and uses Java based libraries.

Luckily, there is a **Node.js** supported JavaScript npm module available named [**jose**](https://github.com/panva/jose), which can handle this in **NodeJS**.

Just `npm install jose` then follow the below code sample:

```
import crypto from "crypto";
import * as jose from "jose";
...
...
...
const { plaintext, protectedHeader } = await jose.compactDecrypt(
    req.body.integrity_token, 
    Buffer.from(config.DECRYPTION_KEY, "base64"
)); /* integrity_token is the token got from Integrity API response in the app. 
DECRYPTION_KEY is found from Google Play Console */

console.log(protectedHeader);
console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(plaintext));

const { payload, Header = protectedHeader } = await jose.compactVerify(
    plaintext, 
    crypto.createPublicKey("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" + 
        config.VERIFICATION_KEY + 
        "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----")
);

console.log(Header);
const payloadText = new TextDecoder().decode(payload);
console.log(payloadText);
const payloadJson = JSON.parse(payloadText);

console.log(payloadJson.requestDetails.nonce); /* the encrypted nonce message sent from app. */

console.log(Buffer.from(
    payloadJson.requestDetails.nonce, 
    "base64"
).toString()); /* the actual nonce message sent from app. */
```

To get **Decryption key** and **Verification key** from Google Play Console, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72456808/1367858).

Comment: Which jose version is it?

Comment: @HimanshuSharma at the time of writing, it was version 4.9.3.