# Why does the JWE decryption fail? Google Integrity in node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, encryption, jwt

I'm writing a reverse proxy in node.js/express to make API calls safer. Here's the code for decoding a JWE sent by google according to this documentation:

```
app.get('/checkGoogleToken', async (req, res) => {
    const tokens = fs.readdirSync('./tokens/')
    console.log('Checking Google Token')
    const token = fs.readFileSync('./tokens/' + tokens[0], 'utf-8')
    console.log(token)
    const { plaintext, protectedHeader } = await jose.compactDecrypt(
        token,
        Buffer.from(process.env.DECRYPTION_KEY, "base64"
        )); /* integrity_token is the token got from Integrity API response in the app. 
    DECRYPTION_KEY is found from Google Play Console */

    console.log(protectedHeader);
    console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(plaintext));

    const { payload, Header = protectedHeader } = await jose.compactVerify(
        plaintext,
        crypto.createPublicKey("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
            process.env.VERIFICATION_KEY +
            "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----")
    )
```

I found the code here: [Decrypt and verify locally Play Integrity API Token using NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815156/decrypt-and-verify-locally-play-integrity-api-token-using-nodejs)

However, even though the DECRYPTION_KEY is the one provided by Google, the decryption fails. The files in /tokens/ are plain text files containing the JWE token which my test phone saved after receiving them.
There is one little detail, though. I am so far executing the app from expo via metro, i.e. not through a proper installation through the play store (in order to speed up testing)... could this lead to a different key being used to encrypt to JWE?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
For anyone running into this problem in the future: The code above and in the linked question is 100% correct. Google Play Integrity only works the way you define it in the Play Console if installed via the Play Store (this works with testing versions, too, though). So if you need to fiddle with Integrity, my tip is to do it at the very end of the development process and then do it via testing distribution.